# Doctrine with SQL Server DateTime type

Tags: sql-server, doctrine

I work on a Web application on Laravel which relies on Doctrine. The Database is stored on SQL Express 2017.

I had a problem with the DateTime type as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/known-vendor-issues.html#microsoft-sql-server) when I do a SELECT.

***Could not convert database value "2018-11-19 16:19:44.923" to Doctrine Type datetimetz. Expected format: Y-m-d H:i:s.u P***

To solve this I created my own DateTime Type after some research.

```
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class MsDateTime extends DateTimeType
{
    private $dateTimeFormatString = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ($value !== null) ? $value->format($this->dateTimeFormatString) : null;
    }

}
```

Then I override the default type :

```
Type::overrideType(Type::DATETIMETZ, 'App\Doctrine\Types\MsDateTime');
```

So now I can display data but I can't insert new rows :
*An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO table (row1, row2, active, date_created, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["Test", "Test", 1, "2018-11-20 16:12:11.349245", "2018-11-20 16:12:11.349250"]*

I would like to know why I can't store new rows. If you have any fix for Doctrine with SQLServer I would be very grateful !

We also use Python with SQL Alchemy to query the same database and we don't have this kind of problem.

Comment: can you change the date string format so that it is  20181120 16:12:11.349245, also that may be too many decimal places for DateTime, you may need DateTime2 in SQL.  The YYYYMMDD is ISO date format for SQL, almost always works in SQL strings.

Comment: I set the datetime format in SQL EXPRESS to Datetime2. However I can update/insert but not select. I got Expected format: Y-m-d H:i:s.u P.

Answer (score 1):

Working with Microsoft Sql Server Express 2017, you should first verify that you use the `SQLServer2012Platform` in your Doctrine configuration/autoloader.

I specify it the following way (under Codeigniter) :

```
$myPlatform = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SQLServer2012Platform();
$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlsrv',
    'user' => $db['default']['username'],
    'password' => $db['default']['password'],
    'host' => $db['default']['hostname'],
    'dbname' => $db['default']['database'],
    'platform' => $myPlatform
);
```

I switched all my SQL fields from `DATETIME` to `DATETIME2` and inserts/update are working well.

My Doctrine entities are defined with 'datetime' type, and I can feed them with native `DateTime()` objects.

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable = true)
 */
protected $created;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable = true)
 */
protected $updated;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function updatedTimestamps(): void
{
    if ($this->created === null) {
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
    }
    $this->updated = new \DateTime();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Following the known issues, I would abandon the datetimetz type. See
[Doctrine - Known Vendor Issues - Microsoft SQL Server](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/known-vendor-issues.html#microsoft-sql-server)